# redirect language .htaccess only for root

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect the visitor on the language from his navigator but only from the root.
I have used this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Force the "www." at the beginning of URLs #-----------------
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Language redirection  #----------
# French
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) /?lang=fr [QSA,L]
# English
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) /?lang=en [QSA,L]
```

it works but not perfectly; i got 2 problem;
first one, the url is not really rewrite; the param ?lang=en is not write in the url; even if the page is the good one in english.

The second problem, is that if i had a R=302 or 301
like this:

```
    RewriteRule (.*) /?lang=en [QSA,R,L]
```

i got a loop and my website bug on this url www.mywebsite.com/?lang=en?lang=en?lang=en?lang=en?lang=en?lang=en?lang=en?lang=en etc...

whats wrong in my code ?

Sincerely.
Paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your rules like this:

```
# Force the "www." at the beginning of URLs #-----------------
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# make english default lang
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !^(en|fr) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)lang=(?:en|fr) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /?lang=en [QSA,L,R]

# Language redirection  #----------
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^(en|fr) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)lang=(?:en|fr) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /?lang=%1 [QSA,L,R]
```

Comment: I think you have to do it with `(fr|en)` for a site in 2 languages

Comment: Yes sure it can be restricted to 2 languages like that.

Comment: @Croises anubhava's answer allows him to have more languages later without modifying the rules. It's more dynamic now.

Comment: @PanamaJack Yes, but it also adds a language in the link, that is not necessarily available for the site. I would not like that for one of my sites in 2 languages. But it is also true that I look for what is the best positioned language (if not first), not easy with htaccess.

Comment: @Croises yes, easy enough to handle in the code. Just set your default language if it's not availble. I would rather handle that part with PHP.

Comment: @PanamaJack The problem if you redirect with languages that do not exist, you must also take care to manage the duplicate content (for example for Google), and you have to do that in your html code. Or redirect again after...

Comment: @Croises Well it's not my scenario so, it's up to the OP how he wants to handle it.

Comment: @croises i think i prefer your solution <code># Language redirection  #----------
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^(fr|en) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=(fr|en) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /?lang=%1 [QSA,L,R]</code> is that right like this ?

Comment: A last question, is there a way to make the english language the default language ? ( I will add german and chinesse maybe next; but could be great if japonese visitor or else comes to the website that he get the ?lang=en )

Comment: @anubhava Yeaah perfect ! thanks again for you answer and your reactivity ;-) ! have a good day.